# Прибавление дней k дней к дате

Tags: классы, pascal, дата, типы

Подскажите пожалуйста, как добавить k дней (допустим 180, может быть и больше года) к дате формата:

```
  t_date = record
    day: 1..31;
    month: 1..12;
    year: 2000..3000;
  end;
```

Вообще идей ни каких, так как нужно учитывать много факторов одновременно, типа начала нового года, високосный ли год и сколько дней в месяце, помогите пожалуйста. Функциями для работы с датой пользоваться нельзя, так бы я и сам бы всё сделал.

Comment: Ну например сделать пересчет даты в число дней, прошедших с даты Х (где-нибудь далеко в прошлом), потом прибавить число дней, сделать обратный пересчет. Пересчеты туда-сюда сами по себе должны быть проще.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, костяк процедуры AddDays, например, такой ( не факт, что оптимизировано). Мог ошибиться, т.к. писал не в IDE.

```
const
   daysinmonth:array[1..12] of integer = (31, 28, 31,...); // количество дней в месяцах
   daysinmonth_v:array[1..12] of integer = (31, 29, 31,...); // количество дней в месяцах для високосного года

function Visokosny(d:integer):boolean;
begin
  Result:=true если d- високосный год, иначе false; // Думаю, сами напишете
end;


procedure AddDays(k:days; var td:t_date);
var
  y, m, d:integer;
begin
   y:=td.year;
   m:=td.month;
   d:=td.day;
   while k >= 365 do       
      begin
         if Visokosny(y) then
            begin
               if k=365 then break // разумеется, здесь можно сразу всё прибавить и закончить процедуру - тут вам решать
              else dec(k,366);
            end
         else dec(k, 365);
         inc(y);
      end; // целые годы прибавили
   if k > 0 then
       begin
          repeat
            if Visokosny(y) then
              begin
                 if (d+k) > daysinmonth_v[m] then
                   begin
                      dec(k,daysinmonth_v[m]);
                      inc(m);
                      if m > 12 then
                        begin
                          m:=1;
                          inc(y);
                        end;
                   end
                 else break; 
              end
           else       
              begin
                 if (d+k) > daysinmonth[m] then
                   begin
                      dec(k,daysinmonth[m]);
                      inc(m);
                      if m > 12 then
                        begin
                          m:=1;
                          inc(y);
                        end;
                   end
                 else break; 
              end
          until false; // пробежали по месяцам
          inc(d,k);
       end;
   td.year:=y;
   td.month:=m;
   td.day:=d;

end;
```

Comment: Поправьте меня, но вроде в TDateTime целая часть - это количество дней с какой-то даты. Т.е. сначала EncodeDate, потом прибавить дни, потом DecodeDate - так не проще будет? Или в паскале такого типа еще не было?

Comment: @Alekcvp Прочтите внимательно вопрос автора: нельзя пользоваться функциями работы с датой.

Comment: Упс, упустил с недосыпу :)